# GROUP BY but ignore nulls unless no not-nulls

Tags: mysql, sql

(I'm simplifying my data for sake of explanation)

I have a denormalized table (basically the result of a join between 3 different tables) like this:

```
driver_uuid | vehicle_uuid | document_uuid
```

A driver has many vehicles,
A driver has many documents,
A vehicle has many documents

I want to run a query where there is a row for each unique driver/vehicle pair.

I tried just doing

```
SELECT * FROM driver_vehicle_documents
GROUP BY 
driver_uuid,
vehicle_uuid
```

This almost works, but with one problem:

A driver that has 1 or more vehicles will show up one more time than the number of vehicles they have. i.e. a driver that has 1 vehicle will show up twice: once for the driver/vehicle pair, and once for driver/null pair.

We want it so that a driver that has 0 vehicles will show up once. A driver with 1 vehicle will show up once, a driver with 2 vehicles will show up twice, etc.

---

I know the table design is not ideal for this problem, but the table is used for many different purposes and was designed with those considerations. Changing its design is not feasible at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have two lists; a list of drivers and a list of vehicles.

You want the complete list of drivers, plus any vehicle records if they exist.

You can accomplish this with a self-outer-join, like this:

```
SELECT    drivers.driver_uuid,
          vehicles.vehicle_uuid,
          vehicles.document_uuid
FROM      driver_vehicle_documents drivers
LEFT JOIN driver_vehicle_documents vehicles ON  vehicles.driver_uuid = drivers.driver_uuid 
                                            AND vehicles.vehicle_uuid IS NOT NULL
```

The join will only allow records where there is a vehicle ID.  But if none are found, the driver record will still be output (because it's an outer join) and the vehicle and document IDs will just come back as null.

Comment: This worked! Modified it a bit to fit the actual implementation of our table and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's a miracle (I wasn't sure)!

Answer (score 1):

On approach is to handle the `NULL` values separately.  So, basically run your query filtering out `NULL` values and then add back in the ones you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT driver_uuid, vehicle_uuid
FROM driver_vehicle_documents
WHERE vehicle_uuid
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT driver_uuid, NULL
FROM driver_vehicle_documents dvd
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM driver_vehicle_documents dvd2
                  WHERE dvd2.driver_uuid = dvd.driver_uuid AND
                        dvd2.vehicle_uuid IS NOT NULL
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems rather straight forward: filter out `null` values and do not include the third column

Seems rather straight forward: filter out null values and do not include the third column

```
SELECT driver_uuid, 0
FROM driver_vehicle_documents
WHERE vehicle_uuid  is null
GROUP BY 
    driver_uuid,
    vehicle_uuid

UNION ALL

SELECT driver_uuid, vehicle_uuid 
FROM driver_vehicle_documents
WHERE vehicle_uuid  is not null
GROUP BY 
    driver_uuid,
    vehicle_uuid
```